# android set ImageView src by parameter

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I need set image resource by Send parameter (`String src`)

I have this code

```
public void getSource(View view , String src){

    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    image.setImageURI(src);
}
```

How do I solve this problem ؟

Comment: use picasso library http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Send parameter? what "Send parameter" do you mean?

Comment: @pskink I have 3 images in drawable folder , I need set ImageView src by prameter of method

Comment: I don't quite get your question, Maybe this will help
[ImageView][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

```
// method to call to set image

   private void setImage(int src) {
       ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.your_image_view);
       iv.setImageResource(src);
   }
```

//Pass your resource and use it like this :-

```
setImage(R.drawable.plus_active);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set image from local storage, then you have to get the uri of the image and use setImageUri like this:
  public void getSource(View view , String srcImageUri){

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(src));
}
```

If you have image in drawable folder , then you have to set image like this:

```
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageName);
```

And if you want to set image from web url, then you have to use libraries like picaso or fresco.

Answer (score 1):

use `getResources().getIdentifier();` (there you can pass the **image name String** as a **parameter** to `getIdentifier()` function) to get the **resourceID** of the named image and then use `setImageResource(resourceID);` to set the image to **ImageView**.

```
public void getSource(View view , String src){
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier( src, "drawable", Context.getPackageName());
    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    image.setImageResource(resID);
}
```

you may need to pass the `Context` as a parameter to your `getSource()` function.